# DotConnect PostgreSQL Update Command

Tags: postgresql, dotconnect

```
        string finalResult = "Failed";

        using (PgSqlConnection myConnect = new PgSqlConnection(Resources.MyResources.DotConnectNewConnectionString))
        {
            try
            {
                myConnect.Open();

                using (PgSqlCommand cmd = new PgSqlCommand("UPDATE salesforce.ent_inbound_correspondence_entity__c SET status__c = :status, status_change_date__c = CAST(:currentDate AS Date) WHERE deal_id__c = :projID AND correspondence_type__c= :cortype", myConnect))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("status", status);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("currentDate", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("projID", projectID);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("cortype", "704(b) Model");

                    int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
                    if (result > 0)
                    {
                        finalResult = "Success";
                    }
                }

            }
            catch (PgSqlException ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                myConnect.Close();
            }
        }

        return finalResult;
```

Hi All,

I am currently facing an issue when it comes to running an UPDATE query using DotConnect and PgSqlCommand. There are no exceptions occuring BUT whenever this is ran, cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() returns me 0. However, when I execute this query using 'absolute' values in PgAdmin, it has no issues at all.

Can anybody enlighten me on what is wrong with this piece of code? :(

Thank you!

EDIT: An exception message occurs with the following message: Message = "function get_xmlbinary() does not exist"

However, this function is not coded by me. I have no idea what this means.

Comment: check whether your `projID`  have the desired value to update. I mean in where condition

Comment: Hi @Santhucool, Yes. All the desired parameter values are present.